# How to define a Property that it's the keyword like 'checked'?

Tags: c#, properties

Who can help me to resolve the question?
When I defined the Property 'checked' in a class,It's always not passed.

```
Example:
   public class Node
    {
        public bool checked
        {
            get;set;
        }
    }
```

I do so because of I am using a jquery plugin which the return json object's property is checked

I will be very grateful if somebody help me
Thank you

Comment: It's not clear whether you are asking if the `checked` keyword can be applied to a property (which it can't) or if you're trying to name a property 'checked' (which is bad, since property names should use Pascal casing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use a reserved word  as an identifier (which you should avoid anyway), prefix it with the `@` symbol. So your code would be:

```
public class Node
{
    public bool @checked
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this also means you will need to use the `@` symbol when referencing the property. It also won't appear in Visual Studio's IntelliSense listing.

Comment: Thank you your help,you are right,it passed to prefix it with the @ symbol

Answer (score 1):

You can't put this keyword in front of a variable declaration like `readonly`. See [how to use the `checked` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx). I think you want:

```
public int MyProperty
{
  get
  {
    checked
    {
       //maybe a overflow here
    }
    //non-checked code here
  }
}
```

Comment: @JejuneWolf: It's not a good idea to use a keyword as a variable name. Simply change it to `Checked`.